# Product attribute documentation

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating extension to magento 1.9.2.1  and I wondering where can I find information about create product attributes.
I create attribute followeing this article

http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.com/2014/03/create-product-attribute.html

And everything work. But how would I know what special parameter mean.

In magento Api documentation

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.info.html

is describe a few parameters,but where can I find allowed types?, or what does group mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"group" key allows you to choose tab in product edit form in which your attribute will be displayed.

Review `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::_prepareValues()` method to check what array keys you can use.

Reviewing `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute()` can show you more details about using "group", "user_defined", "sort_order" and "option" keys.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I reviewed these files, but I expected  description above these method. Describe parameters above method is common practice. I thought that I can find documentation somewhere, but if not  i will read these mathod more detailed

Comment: @PiotrGalas you can use description for catalogProductAttributeEntity from Magento API documentation from link you showed in your question. Also search for "->addAttribute(" in Magento core code, you fill find a lot of examples.